# Converting time difference to a given format in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting

How do I convert `EVENT_DATE_B - EVENT_DATE_A` which is a number of days to string with `HH:MM` format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If dates are differ only in time part you can use interval day to second. For instance:

```
SQL> select (to_date('25.12.12 15:37:32', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')
  2        - to_date('25.12.12 12:45:45', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')) day(0) to second(0) as Time
  3    from dual
  4  ;

TIME
-------------
+0 02:51:47
```

But obviously it will not always be the case. So you could write a long query to calculate different parts of time, but I think I would go with this simple function:

```
SQL> create or replace function DaysToTime(p_val in number)
  2  return varchar2
  3  is
  4    l_hours    number;
  5    l_minutes  number;
  6    l_seconds  number;
  7  begin
  8    l_Hours := 24 * p_val;
  9    l_minutes := (l_hours - trunc(l_hours)) * 60;
 10    l_seconds := (l_minutes - trunc(l_minutes)) * 60;
 11    return to_char(trunc(l_hours), 'fm09')  ||':'||
 12           to_char(trunc(l_minutes), 'fm09')||':'||
 13           to_char(trunc(l_seconds), 'fm09');
 14  end;
 15  /

Function created
```

And now the query would be:

```
SQL> select DaysToTime(to_date('25.12.12 15:37:32', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')
  2        - to_date('25.12.12 12:45:45', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')) as Time
  3    from dual
  4  ;

TIME
----------
02:51:47
```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach (one query can be on different days):

```
with tt as (
   select numToDsinterval((EVENT_DATE_B - EVENT_DATE_A ), 'DAY') dsint 
     from t)
select (extract(day from dsint)*24)+extract(hour from dsint) || 
       ':' ||extract(minute from dsint)
from tt
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09281/1)

Comment: +1 Of course. For some reason I hadn't thought about `NumToDSInterval` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select 24 * (EVENT_DATE_B - EVENT_DATE_A) || ':' || '00'
from your_table
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/5415)

Comment: `EVENT_DATE_B - EVENT_DATE_A` may not be an integer

Comment: That's no good for something like `select 24*(to_date('25.12.12 15:37:32', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS') - to_date('25.12.12 12:45:45', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')) || ':' || '00' from dual`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to find out the number of days between date1 and date2, then subtract this difference from date2 and convert final date to your format. Copy/paste and see the output:

```
Select date2, days_between, to_char(date2-days_between, 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') end_date
From
(
Select sysdate date2 
     , trunc(sysdate)-to_date('20-DEC-2012') days_between  --'20-DEC' is start_date
From dual
)
/
```